# How to divide each item of a list by a specific sum of two items from different list

Tags: r

Suppose I have lists such this:

```
x <- list(rnorm(10, 0, 2), rnorm(10, 0, 3))
z <- list(rnorm(10, 1, 2), rnorm(10, 1, 3))
d <- list(x,z)
```

Then, I would like to sum the first vector of the first list with the first vector of the second list. And the second vector of the first list with the second vector of the second list. That is, I would like to sum the corresponding vectors. The first of the first list with the first of the second and so on. Then, divide the first vector of the first list by the first some. The same for the first vector of the second list and so on.

```
y1 <- d[[1]][[1]]+d[[2]][[1]]
y2 <– d[[1]][[2]]+d[[2]][[2]]
```

Then, I would like to divide the first vector of the first list by the first sum. The same for the first vector of the second list. Then divide the second vector of each list by the second sum. Such this:

```
d[[1]][[1]]/y1
d[[1]][[2]]/y2
d[[2]][[1]]/y1
d[[2]][[2]]/y2
```

I can do this manually, however, how could I do this for arbitrary number of element of the list. That is, suppose I have `2` list each with `10` vectors.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `reduce` after `transpose`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
    transpose %>%
    map(~ .x %>% reduce(`+`))
```

For the second part, extend the above

```
out <- d %>% 
       transpose %>% 
       map(~ .x %>% reduce(`+`)) %>% #get the sum
       replicate(length(d), ., simplify = FALSE) %>% #replicate to make lengths same
       map2(d, ., ~ map2(.x, .y, `/`)) #loop through the nested elements and divide

identical(out[[1]][[1]],  d[[1]][[1]]/y1)
#[1] TRUE

identical(out[[1]][[2]],  d[[1]][[2]]/y2)
#[1] TRUE
```